# Compile a program written for Windows CE to run on a Windows WM device

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a program written in vb.net and compiled in Visual Studion 2005 for Windows CE 5.0.  It works fine on a Windows CE device.  I am trying to run it on another device which has Windows WM.  It will load, but doesn't respond to any commands.  My understanding is that I need to recompile it with different libraries (per Motorolla - the device manufacturer) that are compatible with Windows CM.  My problem is that I am new to the mobile environment and don't know how to find what I need and set up the environment.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you

Comment: While there *are* some differences sometimes, generally speaking a .NET CF 3.5 based application should run just fine on both Win CE and WM. You will have to give more details on the specific problem you are encountering.

Comment: I can put the application on a WM device, start it, but when I tap any button or try to enter any data, there is no response.

Comment: Do you have any modal dialog boxes in your application? Its entirely possible one of them has popped up behind your app. Especially if you mess with the window Z-order.